# Has the OPCW submitted its report relevant to the alleged April 7, 2018 chemical weapon attack in Douma to the organisation's member states?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, syria, chemical-weapons

Has the [Organisation for the Prohibition of Chemical Weapons](https://www.opcw.org/) (OPCW) submitted its report relevant to the alleged April 7, 2018 chemical weapon attack in Douma to the organisation's member states?

If not, is there a timeline which the organisation is following as to when the report will be submitted to the organisation's member states?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OPCW released [an interim report on Jul 6](https://www.opcw.org/news/article/opcw-issues-fact-finding-mission-reports-on-chemical-weapons-use-allegations-in-douma-syria-in-2018-and-in-al-hamadaniya-and-karm-al-tarrab-in-2016/):

> OPCW designated labs conducted analysis of prioritised samples. The results show that no organophosphorous nerve agents or their degradation products were detected in the environmental samples or in the plasma samples taken from alleged casualties. Along with explosive residues, various chlorinated organic chemicals were found in samples from two sites, for which there is full chain of custody. Work by the team to establish the significance of these results is on-going. The FFM team will continue its work to draw final conclusions.

So basically: no nerve gas, but chlorine. There's no timeline specified in there for the final report.

Comment: "So basically: no nerve gas, but chlorine." wrong, these are traces of chlorine of an unknown origin. Have you heard about the Syrian and Russian allegations  about the Syrian terrorists planting CW attack evidence? Then of course it is difficult to understand why the Syrian government would want to commit suicide by using CW, but it is not difficult at all to imagine why would the terrorists want to make it seem that such an attack took place. BTW, in case I hurt your sensibility by calling terrorists terrorists, this is how such people would be called in any western state.

Comment: @JohnDonn: what you describe is indeed the Russian position: http://www.euronews.com/2018/04/27/witnesses-claim-douma-chemical-attack-was-staged Or at least was in April. I don't know if the Russians have said anything on the interim report, which by the way does not pin blame for the attack on anyone in particular, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh yeah, they described it as "anti-Syrian" a few days before it was even released: http://www.rudaw.net/english/world/22062018